# JSX not rendering after .map in React

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

I am fetching a JSON file and trying to render the data from it. Everything shows up great when I console.log it but the JSX is not being rendered to the page. I was using forEach and read that it should be map instead but that doesn't fix my problem. Here's my code:

```js
getPromoDetails(data) {
  data = this.state.data;
  Object.keys(data || {}).map(function(key) {

    console.log("Promo ID: ",data[key].cm_ID)
    console.log("Title: ",data[key].cm_title)
    console.log("State: ",data[key].state)
    console.log("Status: ",data[key].status)
    console.log("Last Modified on: ",data[key].cm_lastmodified)

  return
    <div className="col-xs-12">
      <div className="col-xs-3">
        <img src={`https://link.com/thumbnail_${data[key].cm_ID}.jpg`}/>
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-9">
        <span className="col-xs-12"> {data[key].cm_title}</span>
        <span>On: {data[key].cm_on}</span>
        <span>State: {data[key].state}</span>
        <span>Status: {data[key].status}</span>
        <span>Last Modified: {data[key].cm_lastmodified}</span>

      </div>
    </div>
  });
}
```

Any advice??

Comment: Is this a function?

Comment: Yes it did @Tholle ! Thank you very much

Comment: Great! No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning the array that is the result of the `map`. You also have to make sure the JSX is on the same line as the `return` statement, or `undefined` will be returned.

```js
getPromoDetails() {
  const { data } = this.state;

  return Object.keys(data || {}).map(function(key) {
    return (
      <div className="col-xs-12" key={key}>
        <div className="col-xs-3">
          <img src={`https://link.com/thumbnail_${data[key].cm_ID}.jpg`} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-9">
          <span className="col-xs-12"> {data[key].cm_title}</span>
          <span>On: {data[key].cm_on}</span>
          <span>State: {data[key].state}</span>
          <span>Status: {data[key].status}</span>
          <span>Last Modified: {data[key].cm_lastmodified}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```